# Error during using enum in C

Tags: c

I try to make enum for assembly instructions,

```
 typedef enum opcode {load, loada, store, mov, add, sub, mul, div, mod, cmp,   b, blt, ble, bne, beq, bge, bgt, read, write}OP_CODE;
```

but I get this error because, I think, some of the instruction is already define in C.

```
DEF.h:13:62: error: ‘div’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 typedef enum opcode {load, loada, store, mov, add, sub, mul, div, mod, cmp, b,
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem.
I cannot change the words or the case letters. 
Thanks

Comment: It appears that `div` is already declared prior to the definition of `opcode`.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `extern div_t div (int __numer, int __denom)` in stdlib.h.

Comment: `div` is a library function in both C and C++, declared in `stdlib.h` and `cstdlib` respectively.

Comment: In C++ it's a good idea to reserve all uppercase identifiers for macros. It's also a good idea to use only one name for a thing.

Comment: Given the number of opcode names, and their short names, I would use a prefix for all of them.  For instance, `op_load`, `op_div`, `op_cmp`, etc.

Comment: Why can't you change the names?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are in C, cannot rename the words and cannot change the case, and you don't want also to mess with the libraries... no much choice.

**You could create a *struct***

```
typedef struct {int load, loada, store, mov, add, sub, mul, div, mod, cmp, b,
                blt, ble, bne, beq, bge, bgt, read, write;
} OP_CODE;
```

Assign member values

```
OP_CODE op;
op.load  = 1;
op.loada = 2;
...
```

and use `op.`*opcode* wherever necessary.

---

**Use #define**

The other workaround which will do exactly what you want is not very clean

- the `#define` have to be declared *after* the headers includes
- you cannot use the definitions that you *define* from the libraries anymore

for instance

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
#define load  1
#define loada 2
....
```

Then you can use the names as is

```
if (opcode == div) { 
    // do div stuff
}
```

Not recommended but if you *have to* use the names as they are in C, that's the solution (note that a few *defines* are used a lot in C, like *read* and *write* to name two, to read and write files).

Answer (score 2):

`div` is a library function, so you should not use the same name.  So you should  "change the words or the case letters" (or change the compiler to C++ and use namespace to isolate your enumeration).

You can rename all members of your enum, e.g.

```
 typedef enum opcode {LOAD, LOADA, STORE, MOV, ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, MOD, CMP, B, BLT, BLE, BNE, BEQ, BGE, BGT, READ, WRITE} OP_CODE;
```

or

```
 typedef enum opcode {op_load, op_loada, op_store, op_mov, op_add, op_sub, op_mul, op_div, op_mod, op_cmp, op_b, op_blt, op_ble, op_bne, op_beq, op_bge, op_bgt, op_read, op_write} OP_CODE;
```

I prefer the last option (with prefix added to names of all values of `opcode`)

Comment: OP said (s)he cannot change the case. Nor the names.

Comment: I need to keep name ans case.

Comment: So, leave C++ tag, delete C and make names pace with not standard name. Can you explain restriction about names? Your IDE does not support "rename in all files" or is any other reason?

Comment: This is a good solution.  The only reason I can think of not to be able to modify the names with a prefix is if this task was assigned and that was an arbitrary restriction.  But the point is, you cannot use bare names like `div`, so some sort of prefix is needed, like it or not.  At least with this, the conversion between the bare names and the prefixed names is completely mechanical.

Answer (score 2):

`div` is a standard function [defined in `stdlib.h`].  Since you can't change the names [or case], there are several workarounds.

The first is:

```
#define div __not_div__
#include <stdlib.h>
#undef div

typedef enum opcode {
    load,
    loada,
    store,
    mov,
    add,
    sub,
    mul,
    div,
    mod,
    cmp,
    b,
    blt,
    ble,
    bne,
    beq,
    bge,
    bgt,
    read,
    write
} OP_CODE;
```

The second is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum opcode {
    load,
    loada,
    store,
    mov,
    add,
    sub,
    mul,
    _div,
    mod,
    cmp,
    b,
    blt,
    ble,
    bne,
    beq,
    bge,
    bgt,
    read,
    write
} OP_CODE;

#define div _div
```

The third is [to use `#define` instead of `enum`]:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define load    0
#define loada   1
#define store   2
#define mov     3
#define add     4
#define sub     5
#define mul     6
#define div     7
#define mod     8
#define cmp     9
#define b       10
#define blt     11
#define ble     12
#define bne     13
#define beq     14
#define bge     15
#define bgt     16
#define read    17
#define write   18
```

The fourth option is to simply structure your code so that any file that needs `OP_CODE` does *not* include `stdlib.h` [or vice versa]

Comment: You didn't just happened to copy my *#define* solution, did you?

Comment: @ringø Absolutely _not_. Like minds just think alike. On a different page today, I was going to post an answer but someone posted a comment with my solution, so I just left it as is [a miss of less than a minute]. I've used the `#define` solution in my own code many times before.